# Selenium Web driver: How to get preceding element from a nested span text using Java code?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, parent-child

I have a web page with below HTML format. This is just a sample and a part of code.

```
 <div id="content">
     ........... Many other tags go in here......
     <div id="1234"> // This id number is not constant and so cant hard code in xpath
        <img class="float-right ng-scope" width="85" data-ng-click="highlightItem()" data-ng  if="showThumbnail" ng-src="/server/image" src="/server/image">
        <p>
           <span data-ng-transclude="" data-ng-class="{ selected: isActive }">
                 <span class="ng-scope">My sample text</span>
                 <br class="ng-scope">
           </span>
        </p>
     </div>
    </div>
```

I have the text "My sample text" as my input. (There are many such div blocks and each has different span text). With this, I need to find the img element and click on it. I tried the below code : (referenceText  variable = "My sample text")

```
    String xPath = "//div[@id='content']//span[contains(text(),'" + referenceText + "')]";

    // Get element of the text i.e get span element
    WebElement element = getWebElementByXpath(getWebDriver(), xPath); // Gets span element
   // Works fine !

   // Get its parent element which is again another span
   WebElement parentElement = getParentElement(element, xPath); // Gets next level span
   // Works fine !

   // Get its parent element p
    WebElement grandParentElement = getParentElement(parentElement, xPath); 
   // Does not get its parent element 'p' instead return span element again

   // Get preceding element for p which is img element
    grandParentElement.findElement(By.xpath("./preceding-sibling::img")).click(); 
   // Does not work as element p is not obtained.
```

getParentElement method is as below:

```
  public static WebElement getParentElement(WebElement element, String xPath){
            return element.findElement(By.xpath((xPath + "/..")));
        }
```

Problem : I am able to get the span element and its parent span element but unable to get the p element and its sibling element img. I want to get img element using the span element. Any help on this would be great ! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below XPAth for the image tag having "My sample text" as span value.

```
//div[@id='content']//div[.//span[span='My sample text']]/img
```

Refer http://www.xpathtester.com/xpath/b1d50008dd4be8ab7545548c4b8238f5

Answer (score 0):

Simple open browser and check unique css locator, then check if that locator works for U in java code.

Answer (score 0):

Try this xpath for **getting grandparent 'p' from the 'span', with text "My sample text"**:

```
//span[.='My sample text']/../..
```

Try this xpath for **getting the sibling 'img' of grandparent 'p', from the 'span' with text "My sample text":**

```
//span[.='My sample text']/../../preceding-sibling::img
```

Answer (score 0):

Try out with:

```
//span[.='My sample text']/ancestor::div/img
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help ! The below Xpath worked fine for me.
String xPath = "//div/p/span/span[contains(text(),'My Sample Text')]/../../..//img"